# Apache Can't start because of a make_sock bind to address error on port 80

Tags: apache, apache2

I have noticed a new thing going on with my server that I can't quite figure out what is making it happen.  I'm hoping someone out there has experience with this problem and can help me find a solution to get it to stop.

I did a reboot on my ubuntu server tonight that I have running at slicehost.com.  Everything runs great until I go to start apache.  I get the following error.

> * Starting web server apache2 (98)Address already in use: make_sock:
>   could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   no listening sockets available,
>   shutting down Unable to open logs
>   ...fail!

A little further research using `netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'` will show the following:

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80
>   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3948/apache2

I can then `kill 3948` and apache starts up like normal.  The PID 3948 keeps changing to a different number.

This is new and the only thing I have done since I had a successful boot without this happening was uninstalling a manual install of phpmyadmin and then re-install it using the aptitude install commands.  Phpmyadmin now runs fine on the server but I don't understand what this error means or how I can go about getting it resolved.

Anyone that might offer some insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check If you don't double-start your server, and if your partitions are already mounted, so it can access its log files.

I advice to restate that question on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).com, your question is slightly misplaced here.

Comment: polemon:  Thanks for the reference to serverfault.com  Didn't know about that site.  Just goes to show I never really read the footer of websites that often.  i'll take a look at the double-start issue and see if that's what happening. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because port 80 is already in use (probably IIS7 use it).
 To solve problem open Apache/conf/httpd.conf file and find line **Listen 80** and change it to another port (eg. Listen 5555). Than run httpd.exe and try to open localhost:5555. It works! :)